# How to change dropdown positioning when overflow the dropdown

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to know how to change the position of the second(child) dropdown when overflow the submenu. It now the right side when overflow the menu should be visible in left side.

In this below link visit the identify link before logout under the identify visit identify3 it displays another submenu it should be comes left side, If not overflow it should be in right side only...

http://demos.sanwebcorner.com/matex/

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Post your code **in the question** and explain what's wrong with it

Comment: can you able to understand my query?

Comment: yes. can you understand my comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your css file:

```
menu ul ul ul li {
   right: 170px;
   left: initial !important;
}
```

Comment: You should change your question for future reference, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

just change `left:170px` to `right :170px` in **my-style.css** line 920

```
menu ul ul ul li {
    right: 170px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this so that the style will be applied to the last second child(position where the overflow occurs):

```
menu ul ul ul li:nth-last-child(2)
  {
   right:170px;/* if you want the alignment to be left of the hovered list*?
  }
```

OR

```
menu ul ul ul li:nth-last-child(2)  
{   
 top:0;/* if you want the alignment to be bottom of the hovered list*/ 
   left:0;/*not neccessary if style aren't used in parent class/elements*/
   right:0; 
 }
```